# Calling an overridden method not from a direct father

Tags: c++, inheritance

I came across with a saying that "methods of class in C++ can call all the overridden methods from all levels". For example, consider class A, class B and class C. They have the following hierarchy:

```
A<-B<-C
```

Meaning B ihentence from A and C inhetence from B. All of the classes have a method `foo`. How can I call method `foo` of A from method `foo` of C?

I know it is now possible in Java and C# but is it possible in C++?

Comment: In the same way as you would call B's `foo`: `A::foo();`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [scope resolution operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) with the parent class. e.g:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A"; }
};

class B: public A {
public:
  void foo() override { std::cout << "B"; }
};

class C: public B {
public:
  void foo() override { 
    A::foo();
    B::foo();
    std::cout << "C"; 
  }
};

int main() {
  C c;
  c.foo();
}
```